# How to properly typeset footnotes/superscripts after punctuation marks?

Tags: footnotes, punctuation, typography, best-practices, kerning

I find the spacing of footnote marks after punctuation marks quite unsatisfactory, especially with sans serif fonts and compared to the spacing after letters. Example follows:

[image: normal footnotes]

I came up with a little macro myself that tries to amend this manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
% URW Classico is a font that makes the issue apparent
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% define punctuation-aware footnote macro
\newlength{\punctuationfootlength}
\newcommand{\punctuationfootnote}[2]{#2\settowidth{\punctuationfootlength}%
{#2}\hspace{-\punctuationfootlength}\footnote{#1}}
% define a very small type area and don't care about margins
\setlength{\textwidth}{150pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\noindent The three little pigs built their houses
out of straw\punctuationfootnote{not to be confused with hay},
sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources} and
bricks\punctuationfootnote{probably fired clay bricks}.
\end{document}
```

This will look like this:

[image: full compensation of punctuation marks]

I have to say, I didn't like this either. So I fiddled around a bit and set back the footnote marks by a half

[image: half-width compensation]

and a third of the width of the punctuation mark.

[image: third-width compensation]

Personally, I like the look of the last (`-.3\punctuationfootlength`) the best. But I'm a bit concerned that nobody ever seemed to have shared my opinion on this and if anything put a hair space between a letter and a footnote mark but never decreased the kerning. So if any typography guru here could put me straight on this matter that would be great. I'm also happy about anyone's second or third opinion on this.

---

Edit: Originally I also asked for a better way to TeX this here. As this is a separate question however, I moved it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56094/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-change-kerning-of-commas-and-full-stops-followed).

**Edit 3: That question led to a new package, `fnpct`, which should be used to automatically adapt footnote kerning in your LaTeX document.**

---

Edit 2: Jon's comment caused me to succumb to the temptation I had all along of trying an additional intermediate between solutions 2 and 3. It seems like a ridiculously small change but here is `-.4\punctuationfootlength`:

[image]

Can't decide though. After a bit of pondering, I think I like the 3 a bit closer than the 1 which doesn't make things easier I guess.

Comment: You seem to define `\punctuationfootnote` to have two arguments, but then the macro is called with only one argument, viz., the content of the footnote. Am I missing something? Or is the second argument the punctuation mark? If so, it might be cleaner if you surrounded the punctuation mark with curly braces to make this setup explicit. By the way, the font "URW Classico" would appear to be a clone of Hermann Zapf's famous "Optima" font.

Comment: Yes, the punctuation mark is the second argument and in this case I find the sentence more readable when keeping the punctuation marks visually outside the footnote macro. URW Classico is indeed an Optima clone but one that is free-as-in-beer for LaTeX. I can hardly expect people here to own or buy Optima just to reproduce my example.

Comment: Not sure about this arrangement.  Beyond Mico's point, which I agree with, this does not make for maintainable code: everytime you edit your text you run the risk of having to change `\footnote` to `\punctuationfootnote` and vice-versa.  It gets even worse if you end up publishing in a European journal, where the expectation is that the footnotemark goes inside the punctuation mark!  Also, while the first option looks ridiculous, I'm not convinced that the third is an (amazing) improvement over the default setup: are the complications worth the changes in appearance?

Comment: @jon I agree that an automatic adjustment would be much better but since I don't know how to do this, `\punctuationfootnote` it is. Do I take it that you prefer the second option? Actually, collecting different aesthetic opinions on this was meant to be part of the question. Lastly, I don't understand what you mean by "footnotemark goes inside the punctuation mark". Is it "texttext\footnote{foo}."? This would further argue for omitting the {} of the second argument I guess but that's just a matter of taste anyway.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I guess the third option is best for me, but it doesn't look so much better (if at all) that it is worth the extra effort.  As for some journals, the expectation is that the footnotemark would go:  text text text¹.  Sometimes, you'll even see it surrounded by parentheses (and maybe not superscript --- which looks really weird).  My point is that you should think about where the writing will end up and work within the conventions/expectations of that forum.  As for an 'automatic' solution, you should look at `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker: perhaps it can be turned to your needs.

Comment: It's my PhD thesis so the typography is entirely up to me. Maybe it wasn't worth the effort objectively but these footnotes kept bothering me so I wanted them fixed.

Comment: I kinda like the -.4\punctuationfootlength better. Since this is about esthetics, I will appeal to the **golden ratio** and propose a kerning of (1-1/φ) = -0.381953\punctuationfootlength

Comment: This question is almost two years old and still nobody has suggested the use of an Oxford comma to solve my problem. I am pleasantly surprised by you, Internet.

Comment: This question should probably be edited to put a big warning: "Better use the `fnpct` package, developed from another close question!"

Comment: @Clément Not sure about this. Strictly speaking, this question is off-topic here and belongs on a typography site. De facto, this _is_ the best typography SX site. That other question, which is actually about how to _achieve_ such kerning in LaTeX, is linked, although not prominently. I think I will put a more prominent notice there, even though it messes up the edit structure ;)

Comment: @Christian : you are probably correct, but a rapid search about footnotes and punctuation (cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=footnote+punctuation ) gives this post *before* the one with an explicit link to `fnpct`.

Comment: As a European, they all look equally wrong to me ;).

Comment: @cfr I am European, too, so I'm not quite sure I know what you are hinting at.

Comment: @Christian The punctuation you are aiming at is American, as far as I know. At least, where English is concerned the moving of the marker beyond the punctuation is American rather than British.

Comment: @cfr I don't perceive this as an issue that depends on the side of the Atlantic you're on. Hart's Rules for example also prescribe the footnote going after the punctuation. And, again as a European, I'd say *every* sane style guide does. At least it's true, if you put the punctuation after the footnote mark, kerning is the least of your worries. BTW, `fnpct` include a mode that switches the position of footnote and punctuation mark.

Comment: @Christian I was not entirely serious. At the same time, they all look wrong to me. You may well be right that this has nothing to do with the side of the Atlantic I happened to be born on.  Still, I would like to resist the conclusion that I am insane if possible.

Comment: I will, grudgingly ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(Obligatory Bringhurst reference warning)

[Bringhurst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Typographic_Style) has a few challenging comments about footnotes, including a mild "don't do that", but the relevant one for this question is (The Elements of Typographic Style, v3.2, pp68-69):

> 4.3.2 Check the weight and spacing of superscripts. ... "Superscripts frequently come at the ends of phrases or sentences. If they are high above the line, they can be kerned over a comma or [full stop], but this may endanger readability, especially if the text is set in a modest size."

Comment: I was just trying to remember what it was Bringhurst did say about this and then I found your answer... :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of searching for superscripts in general. I also changed the title of the question accordingly. Do I get it right that Bringhurst's "don't do that" refers to footnotes in general?

Comment: Yes, he thinks sidenotes are better. "... But the academic habit of relegating notes to the foot of the page or the end of the book is a mirror of Victorian social and domestic practice ...[4.3.1]" Actually, the whole piece is full of LOLs.

Comment: Depends on the length of the notes, surely..?  If the footnote needs to contain the original text (in the original language, say), then it is impossible to put it in the margins! (Endnotes are no less frustrating for that.)

Comment: @jon: That's true, but if there's a lot of them you might need something like `ledmac`

Comment: `ledmac` is better for typesetting real editions of texts.  There, in good editions, the footnotes (or 'apparatus') usually consists at least two levels: the 'apparatus criticus' where variants are noted, and the 'apparatus fontium' where citations and allusions to other authors are noted.  Other levels might also be appropriate.  But I was referring more to normal articles.  I just wrote one that has 175 footnotes (in 35 pages), and they contain references to other scholarship, references to medieval texts, and quotations.  Footnotes are the reasonable choice --- and demanded by the journal.

Comment: For the Bringhurst, it's §4.3, if you're looking at other edition.

Answer (score 13):

I guess I'll use a .06em hair space before all regular footnotes as suggested by http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/latex.html (referring to Jan Tschichold) and a negative hair space for punctuation footnotes (actually the link suggests a .08em hair space and `.3\punctuationfootlength` miraculously turned out to be .0828em but still …). This comes close to the manual kerning I felt best about

[image: manual kerning]

```
The three little pigs built their houses out of 
straw,\hspace{-.06em}\footnote{not to be confused with hay} 
sticks\hspace{.07em}\footnote{or lumber according to some sources} and 
bricks.\hspace{-.08em}\footnote{probably fired clay bricks}
```

Talk about putting paper between cast metal sorts …

All together this yields

```
\documentclass{article}
% URW Classico is a font that makes the issue apparent
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% define punctuation-aware footnote macro
\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\kern.06em\origfootnote{#1}}
\newcommand{\punctfootnote}[1]{\kern-.06em\origfootnote{#1}}
% define a very small 
\setlength{\textwidth}{150pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\noindent The three little pigs built their houses out of
straw,\punctfootnote{not to be confused with hay}
sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources} and
bricks.\punctfootnote{probably fired clay bricks}
\end{document}
```

which looks like this:

[image: preliminary final kerning]

This should also resolve the debate about the order and number of arguments since `\punctfootnote` became a drop-in replacement for `\footnote`.

Thanks a lot for your input! Of course further comments are still very welcome.

Comment: Using `\kern-.20em` for `\punctfootnote` will set the number the same space from the text with or without punctuation. This is what I find aesthetically pleasing, and I wanted to share here, just for reference.