# Is there a way to automatically change kerning between commas/full stops and footnote marks?

Tags: footnotes, punctuation, typography, kerning

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct)

Following up on [my question on the kerning of footnote marks after punctuation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56063/how-to-properly-typeset-footnotes-superscripts-after-punctuation-marks), I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve the kerning of footnote marks over a comma or full stop automatically or with a better macro than the one I provided there. I'm going to repeat my result and the macro I suggested.

Here the footnote marks are moved to the left by a little less than a third of the width of the punctuation marks and the normal footnote marks (that is, those that come after any other symbol or letter) are moved right by the same amount, as inspired by http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/latex.html and shown in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56124/13450):

[image: package default compensation]

This is achieved with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% URW Classico is a font that makes the issue apparent
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% define punctuation-aware footnote macro
\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\kern.06em\origfootnote{#1}}
\newcommand{\punctfootnote}[1]{\kern-.06em\origfootnote{#1}}
% define a very small 
\setlength{\textwidth}{150pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\noindent The three little pigs built their houses out of
straw,\punctfootnote{not to be confused with hay}
sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources} and
bricks.\punctfootnote{probably fired clay bricks}
\end{document}
```

Using LuaLaTeX is an option for me. I'm also aware of the [existing question regarding automatic kerning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10455/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-kerning-for-a-specific-character-combination) but I know too little to adapt the LuaLaTeX code there to my problem.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Edit - using the new package:**

With the package [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) now available just use `\usepackage{fnpct}` and make sure the punctuation marks *follow* the footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
% for demonstration purposes only: make the page small!
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=.5\textwidth,
  paperheight=15\baselineskip,
  margin=5pt,
  bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fnpct}

\begin{document}
  \noindent The three little pigs built their houses
  out of straw\footnote{not to be confused with hay},
  sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources}
  and bricks\footnote{probably fired clay bricks}.

  % without `fnpct' for comparison:
  \setfnpct{dont-mess-around}\setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \noindent The three little pigs built their houses
  out of straw\footnote{not to be confused with hay},
  sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources}
  and bricks\footnote{probably fired clay bricks}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**The original answer:**

The following code is an attempt using `expl3`. It uses the [values of your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56124/5049) to your related question: skip back `.06em` if a dot or comma follows else insert `.06em`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% save definition of \footnote
\cs_new_eq:NN \fnpct_orig_footnote:w \footnote

% redefine \footnote
\RenewDocumentCommand \footnote { om }
  { \fnpct_dot_or_comma:nn { #1 } { #2 } }

% internal footnote function:
\cs_new:Npn \fnpct_dot_or_comma:nn #1#2
  {
    % if a dot follows remove it, insert dot, skip back
    % and then insert footnote
    \peek_meaning_remove:NTF .
      {
        . \skip_horizontal:n { -.06em }
        \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
          { \fnpct_orig_footnote:w { #2 } }
          { \fnpct_orig_footnote:w [ #1 ] { #2 } }
      }
      {
        % else do the same with comma
        \peek_meaning_remove:NTF ,
          {
            , \skip_horizontal:n { -.06em }
            \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
              { \fnpct_orig_footnote:w { #2 } }
              { \fnpct_orig_footnote:w [ #1 ] { #2 } }
          }
          {
            % else insert space and then footnote
            \skip_horizontal:n { .06em }
            \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
              { \fnpct_orig_footnote:w { #2 } }
              { \fnpct_orig_footnote:w [ #1 ] { #2 } }
          }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength\textwidth{150pt}
\setlength\textheight{5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\noindent The three little pigs built their houses
out of straw\footnote{not to be confused with hay},
sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources} and
bricks\footnote{probably fired clay bricks}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly the kind of magic I was searching for. Apparently parsing backwards is harder still but this will do nicely. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Should be made into a package BTW. `fixfoot` or something.

Comment: @Christian I am not so sure about that. A package should ensure compatibility with other packages that change footnote behaviour and also treat `\footcite` and similar citing commands the same way... as it is the code is not package material IMHO.

Comment: Yes, treating endnotes and other footnote-style stuff the same would be the main problem.

Comment: @Christian Actually I got intrigued. I'll experiment a little bit and if it turns out not to be too bad I might make a package out of it, probably with a bit more flexibility.

Comment: That would be so great :) Have fun hacking!

Comment: @Christian have a look here if you'd like to do some testing: [bitbucket.org/cgnieder/fnpct](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/fnpct)

Comment: Wow, amazing! That package grew pretty fast and it even got a decent documentation and all. I'm impressed :) I'm sure to keep using this package and I'll contact you immediately when I notice something noteworthy. No news is good news I guess :)

Comment: What shall I say? I have no private life... ;)

Comment: I shouldn't be commenting this at 1 A.M. on a weekday ;)

Comment: This is amazing work! I almost can't keep up with *looking* at the changes. I would feel bad for having caused all this work for you if it wasn't for such an awesome result. Let us hope many people stumble upon this package and subtly improve the typesetting of their footnotes! This might also be the *one* footnote package. To configure them all and in the `\setfnpct` bind them. To show some gratitude, let me award you a post-hoc bounty :)

Comment: Thanks :) There'll be an update in a few days (I'm adding the possibility to add further punctuation marks to the automatism)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: This looks very promising, indeed. I would love to have it as a CTAN package.

Comment: @Daniel it already is: [ctan.org/pkg/fnpct](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct)

Comment: For it to work with French `babel`: `\usepackage[fn-mult-delim=//]{fncpt}`; then `\multfootnote{first//second}` should work like a charm. This is because `;` is treated specially.
For `\footnote{one}\footnote{two}` to work, you will have to set the option `multiple=true` (in v0.4c at least). Great package, with an excellent doc, many thanks to their authors!

Comment: @hdl Be careful, there is a typo in your comment `fncpt` should be `fnpct`.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve your goal, it seems that you have to hack into the `\footnote`command to check the previous character. I am not able to show you workable tex-code, but in the package [footmisc](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc)
*Robin Fairbairns* has coded an option called `multiple`. That option add a comma in between multiple footnote marks, in case you have multiple footnote at the same place. This implies that you have to know that the previous character is footnote mark. Maybe you can adapt the code for your purpose.

The code is commented under section 6.1 in the manual, and it is advanced ... I'm not a TeX-guru, and unable to decode the code.

Your link https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10457/9632 gives answers to the question: Is it possibility to kern two character pairs in LaTeX. `LuaLaTeX` and `fontspec` seems to be the easiest solution. And in this answer; https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53594/9632 ; you will find some `luacode` to adjust kerning on the fly.

On the other hand, maybe it is less work (but less fun) to do it manually, when you do the very last proofreading.

Comment: I don't understand the code either but it doesn't necessarily have to parse backwards – parsing forwards would do just as well. Your second link is one that refers to the first one and I can't figure out how to adapt this for my problem either :/

Comment: @Christian Sorry, this was the best I could come up with. My programming skills are very limited (i.e. nil). I tried, at least. =:-)

Comment: All ideas are welcome. You never know which ones work in advance. Oh and TeX is a nightmare of a language. I wouldn't judge my own programming skills to be nil but most advanced TeX packages look little better than /dev/random to me I must say.