# How to reduce the spacing between punctuation and the superscript citation

Tags: spacing, biblatex, punctuation, superscripts

I'm using biblatex with the `autocite=superscript` option, so I can use `\autocite` to switch the interpunction and a superscript citation when the `\autocite` command is placed before an period or comma. I'd like to move the citation closer to or above the interpunction.

What I want to achieve is shown at the second half of the page: http://www.khirevich.com/latex/footnote_citation/

The solution given on the page consist of a new command that takes both the citation as well as the interpunction as an argument:

```
\newcommand{\sjcitep}[2][]{%       new command with two arguments: optional (#1) and mandatory (#2)
    \settowidth{\spc}{#1}%         set value of \spc variable to the width of #1 argument
    \addtolength{\spc}{-1.8\spc}%  subtract from \spc about two (1.8) of its values making its magnitude negative
    #1%                            print the optional argument
    \hspace*{\spc}%                print an additional negative spacing stored in \spc after #1
    \supershortnotecite{#2}}%      print (cite) the mandatory argument
```

Is it possible to change the `\autocite` command such that it inserts a `\hspace` like in the code above between the interpunction and the superscript whenever it puts the superscript behind an interpunction character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fnpct` package was [developed for comfortably changing interaction with punctuation and footnote marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56094/5049). By default `biblatex`'s commands are not adapted, but `fnpct` offers commands to adapt them manually. See section 8 of the manual for details and impacts.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AdaptNoteOpt\autocite\multautocite

\begin{document}
Without \texttt{fnpct:}

\begingroup\setfnpct{dont-mess-around}
Text\autocite{companion,knuth:ct}. Other text\autocite{companion}, and now
further text. This time we prevent switching\autocite*{knuth:ct:a}.
\endgroup
\bigskip

With \texttt{fnpct}

Text\autocite{companion,knuth:ct}. Other text\autocite{companion}, and now
further text. This time we prevent switching\autocite*{knuth:ct:a}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works great and fnpct has even more options than I was hoping for.

Comment: If you use the `\cite` command, this slightly different adaptation works: `\AdaptNoteOpt\cite\multautocite`.  (It wasn't obvious to me why I needed to do that, but I did.)

Comment: @JoeCorneli this is explained in the manual of `fnpct`

Comment: @JoeCornell BTW: I'd use `\AdaptNoteOpt\cite\multcite` for consistent naming of the commands