# Is there a way to reduce spacing before the footnote call?

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I find the spacing between the word it refers to and the footnote call a bit too large. Is there a way to reduce it ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) package (originating from »[Is there a way to automatically change kerning between commas/full stops and footnote marks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56094/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-change-kerning-between-commas-full-stops-and-foo)«

Answer (score 5):

Please *always* post a complete small document that shows the problem and all classes/packages used. The layout of the footnote marking is under the control of the document class, and you haven't said which you are using.

however the default definition is

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

So you could have

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
  \hbox{\hspace{-.1em}\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother
```

or whatever negative space you want. Note there is no space added by default so any negative space has the potential to make the footnote mark over-print the preceding text.

@tohecz suggests in comments that you have gone

```
word \footnote{this} or word
\footnote{that}
```

In either case the space before the footnote mark is the word space entered into the document not coming from the macro. This again shows the importance of always posting a complete example. If you have spaces before your `\footnote` command do not redefine the command just remove the spaces and use

```
word\footnote{this} or word%
\footnote{that}
```

Comment: I'm suspicious that there's an un-procented end-of-line before `\footnote` or after `\footnote{`, causing some extra space.

Comment: @tohecz ah good guess, I'll add a note expanding that

Comment: @cristelle the redefinition or not putting in spaces?

Comment: the redefinition.

Comment: for more details, I use the book environment with no specific customisation of the footnotes, and of course, no suspicious space or linebreak before the footnote call. It's just an aesthetic appreciation, (maybe a French habit?) `code` n’ont plus cours\footnote{NDT : L’auteure ...}`code`

Comment: Well OK but just beware that (especially if the word ends in a capital) that there is a danger of overprinting as there is no space added initially and you are making it negative space)