# Consecutive \footcite commands and separating commas in the text

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

When using the `\footcite` commands with biblatex, it is not clear how the separating commas in the text should be handled. For instance, `\footcite{key1},\footcite{key2}` will be problematic in the text because of a normal comma separating two exponents. Intead, `\footcite{key1}\textsuperscript{,}\footcite{key2}` should be preferred but looks problematic. What is the right way to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Isn't `\footcite{key1,key2}` working?

Comment: @cgnieder no, it places the two references on the same line in the footnotes, which I want to avoid.

Comment: You should probably add an MWE together with a description of what you _do_ want to get.

Comment: @cgnieder please have a look at MarcoDaniel's example.

Comment: I think what you want is `\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}` and then use `\autocite{key1,key2}`. I added another answer using a different method anyway...

Comment: @cgnieder your autocite solution is interesting but cannot be in footnotes.

Comment: Well, I'm still trying to guess what it is you actually want exactly so I'm just mentioning what comes to mind :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct/) package can be used for this. [While its primary purpose is another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56094/5049) it also can handle multiple `\footcite` commands provided `\footcite` is added to `fnpct`'s known commands. The example below is shamelessly borrowed from [Marco Daniel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123837/5049).  Note that the code below is for fnpct version 1.0 (released January 2021).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{fnpct}
\AdaptNote\footcite{oo+m}[footnote]{%
  \setfnpct{dont-mess-around}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {#NOTE{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {#NOTE[#1]{#3}}
       {#NOTE[#1][#2]{#3}}}}


\begin{document}
Text\footcite{knuth:ct:a}

Text\footcite{knuth:ct:b}\footcite{ctan}


Text\footcite{knuth:ct:c}\footcite{companion}\footcite{knuth:ct:d}

Text\footcite{knuth:ct:a}\footcite{knuth:ct:b}\footcite{knuth:ct:c}\footcite{knuth:ct:d}\footcite{companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something wrong happens when you have add a period at the end of the sentence: `Text\footcite{knuth:ct:b}\footcite{ctan}.`

Comment: @pluton either use `\setfnpct{punct-after}` or `\setfnpct{dont-mess-around}` or have a look at the `fnpct` documentation for further options…

Comment: However, if each footcite command is placed on a seperate line no punctuation marks are palced, is there a way ot of that, I need to place footcites command after each other but each one on a seperate line and not all commands on same line

Comment: @Silva yes. The end of a line is treated by TeX like a space so placing them on different lines is like `\footcite{...} \footcite{...}` where you will notice the same. Hide the end of the line by commenting it: `\footcite{...}%`

Comment: @cgnieder, is there a way to use "fnpct" package instead of "footnoterange"package, I need an alternative to resolve this issue https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531313/conflict-upon-compiling-multiple-tables/531317?noredirect=1#comment1343965_531317

Comment: @cgnieder, The proposed code need some modifications https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596937/multiple-footcite-citations   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511158/231952     \AdaptNoteOpt no longer works, it would be great if you can update the answer

Answer (score 6):

I don't know a way using `biblatex` but I can suggest a self defined command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__pluton_input_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \myfootcite { m  }
 {
   \int_compare:nNnTF
    { \clist_count:n { #1 } } > { 1 }
    { \__pluton_myfootcites:n { #1 } }
    { \footcite { #1 } }
 }
\cs_set:Npn  \__pluton_myfootcites:n #1 
 {
  \clist_set:Nx \l__pluton_input_clist { #1 }
  \int_case:nnn { \clist_count:N \l__pluton_input_clist }
     {
       { 0 } { \footnote{\bfseries empty~argument} }
       { 1 } { \footcite{ \clist_item:Nn \l__pluton_input_clist { 1 } } }
       { 2 } { \footcite{ \clist_item:Nn \l__pluton_input_clist { 1 } }
                \textsuperscript{,}
                \footcite{ \clist_item:Nn \l__pluton_input_clist { 2 } } }
     }
     {
       \footcite{ \clist_item:Nn \l__pluton_input_clist { 1 } }
       \textsuperscript{,}
       \clist_pop:NN  \l__pluton_input_clist \l_tmpa_tl
       \__pluton_myfootcites:n { \l__pluton_input_clist }
     }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Text\myfootcite{knuth:ct:a}

Text\myfootcite{knuth:ct:b,ctan}


Text\myfootcite{knuth:ct:c,companion,knuth:ct:d}

Text\myfootcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: That's nice. Isn't it doable with `biblatex`?

Comment: @pluton: What do you mean? It works with biblatex.

Comment: yes, sorry but you said: "I don't know a way using biblatex"?

Comment: @pluton: yes. But I meant the definition of the macro. So I used expl3.

Comment: @pluton It is possible, but the context-sensitive trackers update on the assumption that the whole citation list is either inside the same footnote or inline. So unless you don't use any of the trackers or you want something fancy like suppression of recurrent footnotes or compact footnote mark lists, a fully biblatex approach is too messy to be worth all the trouble.

Comment: In your example, you cite `knuth:ct:b` twice with two distinct footnotes. Would it be possible to have athe same footnote number instead?

Answer (score 4):

If you want references to be placed on separate lines in footnotes, consider to redefine `\multicitedelim` so that it will add a linebreak if (and only if) the citation command produces footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\iffootnote{\newline}{\addsemicolon\space}}
\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence #1}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{1.7em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text \parencite{A01,B02}.

Some text.\footcite{A01,B02}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting but for some reason I think that what @MarcoDaniel suggests is very similar to what we find in correctly typed books? In your example, there are two distinct references, which should be reflected in the text by two exponents.