# Automatic insertion of commata in consecutive footnote superscripts

Tags: footnotes

In my document, I use both `\footnote` and `\footcite`, and sometimes I use multiple of these commands consecutively. However, in the text, the superscripts are not separated by commata. I have found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123888/72739) to [Consecutive \footcite commands and separating commas in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123814/21344) that supposedly does exactly what I want, but when I try to compile the given example verbatim, I again get superscripts without commata.

What am I doing wrong? I know more or less how to use LaTeX to do basic tasks, but know virtually nothing about how it works internally, so please keep that in mind when answering.

If possible, I would like to not have to use special commands for multiple footnotes that force me to think about whether there is a previous or following footnote, and choose the command accordingly.

I have tried both using pdflatex and lualatex, and I am using the TeX live 2013 distribution. The [log file](http://pastebin.com/YchF7qZa) produced when compiling to get the above's answer's MWE should contain detailed information on the versions of the packages involved, in case that's important.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: True, the answer doesn't work anymore... probably a problem with `fnpct`. I'll have a look...

Comment: That's a bug in `fnpct` introduced some time after I posted the other answer. I found the fix and will send the updated version to CTAN today

Comment: @clemens: Thank you very much for writing and publishing the package in the first place, and for taking care of this bug! If you post an answer here as soon as you've updated the CTAN package, I'd be happy to mark this question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the answer you linked to doesn't work due to a bug in `fnpct` introduced in some of the updates since I answered the other question.

This bug is fixed with version 0.4c (2015/02/20) which is available [now on CTAN and TeX Live](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.ctan.announce/11524).