# Conflict upon compiling multiple tables

Tags: tables

FOr the MWE shown below (I am using Lualatex + Biblatex), the compilation exits with the error (TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].). However, the compilation only runs in one of 2 cases:

- upon compiling each table alone in a separate file.
- upon removing the "FOOTCITE" from the caption of the second table and placing it outside.

I am wondering if this is an issue in the preamble settings or am I missing something.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
%=================================================================================================
%Graphics - pictures - symbols
%=================================================================================================
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
%==================================================================================================
%CROSS-Referencing
%==================================================================================================
\usepackage{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{footnoterange} 
\usepackage[%
  hidelinks,
  hyperindex,
  colorlinks=true,
  breaklinks,
  allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{bookmark}
%===================================================================================================
%Tabular Environment
%===================================================================================================
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
%======================================================================================================
%Babel Package Settings%
%======================================================================================================
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{babel-cop.ini}
[identification]
charset = utf8
version = 0.1
date = 2019-08-25
name.local = ϯⲙⲉⲧⲣⲉⲙⲛ̀ⲭⲏⲙⲓ
name.english = Coptic
name.babel = coptic
tag.bcp47 = cop
tag.opentype = COP
script.name = Coptic
script.tag.bcp47 = Copt
script.tag.opentype = copt
level = 1
encodings = 
derivate = no
[captions]
[date.gregorian]
[date.islamic]
[time.gregorian]
[typography]
[characters]
[numbers]
[counters]
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=cop]{coptic}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[coptic]{rm}[Language=Default]{FreeSerifAvvaShenouda}
\babelcharproperty{980000}[990000]{direction}{al} 
%=============================================================
%BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS%
%=============================================================
\begin{filecontents}{arabic.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{arabic.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {english},
  and              = {{و}{و}},
  page             = {{صفحة}{صفحة}},
  pages            = {{صفحات}{صفحة}},
  references       = {{مراجع}{مراجع}},
  seenote          = {{انظر الملاحظة}{انظر الملاحظة}},
  bibliography   =  {{المصادر}{المصادر}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{arabic}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\textquotedblleft}

\usepackage[%
  language=auto,
  autolang=other,
  citestyle=verbose-note,
  bibstyle=authortitle,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{footnote} 
\makesavenoteenv{figure}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

%So as to have commas between consecutive \footcite command, declare after bibaltex package so as to see the command
\usepackage{fnpct}
\AdaptNoteOpt\footcite\multfootcite
\setfnpct{punct-after=true,mult-fn-sep =،} % you can use the 


\begin{document} 
\chapter{العلامات باللغة القبطية}
\subsection{العلامات القبطية الاصلية}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{center}
\caption
[
أمثلة لكلمات تبدأ تبدأ بحروف ساكنة وتم إضافة حرف متحرك III ببدايتها أو علامة الچنكم XXII ببدايتها
لتسهيل النطق]
{
أمثلة لكلمات تبدأ تبدأ بحروف ساكنة III وتم إضافة حرف متحرك III ببدايتها أو علامة الچنكم XXII ببدايتها
لتسهيل النطق
\begin{footnoterange}
\footcite{Baramosy1888}
\footcite{Tattam2013} 
\footcite{Pachomius1966}
\footcite{Pachomius1969}
\footcite{Pachomius1970}
\footcite{Pachomius1971}
\end{footnoterange}
}
\label{tab:أمثلةالچنكم حروف ساكنة}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|c?{1mm}}
\toprule[1mm]
\textbf{ 
 الكلمة
} 
&
\textbf{
الكلمة بعد أضافة علامة الچنكم XXII في بدايتها
}
&
\textbf{
الكلمة بعد أضافة حرف متحرك III في بدايتها
}
& 
\textbf{
المعنى
}
\\
\midrule[1.25pt]
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ϩⲕⲟ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ϩ̀ⲕⲟ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲉϩⲕⲟ} &يجوع
\\
\midrule[1.25pt]
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲛⲕⲟⲧ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲛ̀ⲕⲟⲧ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲉ̅ⲛⲕⲟⲧ} & ينام
\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{center}
\caption
[
أمثلة لكلمات تبدأ بالحرف
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{("ⲉ"} 
وتبعه أحد الحروف
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{(ⲛ - ⲙ)}  
في اللهجة الصعيدية والبحيرية
]
{
أمثلة لكلمات تبدأ بالحرف
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{(" ⲉ ")} 
وتبعه أحد الحروف
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{(ⲛ - ⲙ)}  
في اللهجة الصعيدية والبحيرية
\footcite{Youseff1992}
}
\label{tab:أمثلةالچنكم حروف متحركة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|c?{1mm}}
\toprule[1mm]
\rowcolor{white}
\textbf{ 
 الكلمة
} 
&
\textbf{
الكلمة البحيرى II
بالچنكم
}
&
\textbf{
الكلمة الصعيدى II
بالچنكم
}
& 
\textbf{
المعنى
}
\\
\midrule[1.25pt]
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲉⲙⲕⲁϩ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲙ̀ⲕⲁϩ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲙ̅ⲕⲁϩ} &ألَم
\\
\midrule[1.25pt]
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲉⲛⲕⲟⲧ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲛ̀ⲕⲟⲧ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲉ̅ⲛⲕⲟⲧ} & ينام
\\
\midrule[1.25pt]
\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲉⲛϩⲟⲧ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲛ̀ϩⲟⲧ} &\foreignlanguage{coptic}{ⲛ̅ϩⲟⲧ} & أمين . مخلص
\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just before you get the stack overflow message you get

```
LaTeX3 Warning: The command '\rmfamily' was undefined but not the associated
(LaTeX3)        commands '\rmfamily code' and/or '\rmfamily defaults'. Maybe
(LaTeX3)        you tried using \let. This may lead to an infinite loop.
```

So I suspect your

```
  \babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
```

commands are causing a loop, this isn't really an answer and I'll mark as cw, just putting a pointer so far...

(I replaced your fonts by ones I had, the actual fonts do not matter to generate the error)

---

actually the error is unrelated to fonts it can be reproduces with this example in luatex or pdftex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{footnoterange}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption
[a]{\begin{footnoterange}
\footcite{Baramosy1888}
\end{footnoterange}
}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption
[a]
{a\footcite{Youseff1992}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same preamble works with other files normally for me. It might be only a matter that the proper fonts are not available on your system

Comment: @Silva I don't think it will matter what your font is, but first I need to try to make a more reasonable test file, your file includes lots_ of code unrelated to the problem: tabu, biblatex etc, which makes it hard to trace

Comment: @Silva see updated example (from Ulrike)

Comment: @ Ulrike, the updated example (from Ulrike) reproduce the same error message upon running in using Lualatex. I included most of the preamble since I was weary that there might be a conflict between any of the packages I used.

Comment: If it is a matter of package incompatibility isuue, can there be any alternative solutions?

Comment: @Silva I have no idea what the footnoterange package does I had not seen it before:-)

Comment: It allows you to reference consecutive footnotes in the form of a range "1-10", instead of "1,2,3,....10".

Comment: @Silva it's probably best to try to avoid footnotes in captions altogether

Comment: @cgneider, is there an alternative to control citation location without putting it inside thr caption?