# Multiple footcite citations

Tags: footnotes, multiple-citations, footcite

I was preparing a document with citations made as footnotes and I needed to separate them with commas, So used the code suggested in the answer to the shown question
[Consecutive \footcite commands and separating commas in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123814/consecutive-footcite-commands-and-separating-commas-in-the-text).

However, upon updating texlive to the 2021 version, the code no longer runs and gives an error.

The issue is in this line:

\AdaptNoteOpt\footcite\multfootcite

I do not know how to fix it, it says undefined control sequence

Upon removing it, everything works fine, but it used to work normally before installing texlive 2021.

I am using lualatex + biblatex

The code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

%==================================================================================================
%CROSS-Referencing
%==================================================================================================

\usepackage{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{footnoterange} 

\usepackage[%
  hidelinks,
  hyperindex,
  colorlinks=true,
  breaklinks,
  allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{bookmark}

%======================================================================================================
%Babel Package Settings%
%======================================================================================================

\usepackage{filecontents}


\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default,main]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\babelcharproperty{980000}[990000]{direction}{al} 


%=============================================================
%BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS%
%=============================================================
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Browning1983,
 author = {Browning, Robert},
 year = {1983},
 title = {Medieval and Modern Greek},
 publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
 langid = {english}
}
@book{bob,
 author = {Browning, Robert},
 year = {1983},
 title = {Medieval and Modern Greek},
 publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
 langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{biblatex}   
  
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


%So as to have commas between consecutive \footcite command, declare after bibaltex package so as to see the command
\usepackage{fnpct}
\AdaptNoteOpt\footcite\multfootcite
\setfnpct{punct-after=true,mult-fn-sep =،} 

%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================
\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
All citations appear correctly upon using a cite command on each citation
\cite{Browning1983}
\cite{bob}
\newline
Citation numbering appear according to the "langid" in reference definition, how to unify output language to a chosen language??
\newline
English numbering \cite{Browning1983}
\newline
\newline
English numbering \cite{bob}
\newline
Issue displaying the second reference upon putting each citation on a separate line
\cite
{
Browning1983,
bob}
\newline
Issue displaying the second reference in the same "cite" command
\cite{Browning1983,bob}
\\
Issue using the cites command
\cites[30]{bob}[40]{bob}[60]{bob}{Browning1983}
\newline
Issue using citec command on more than one line for clarity of coding
\cites
[30]{bob}
[40]{bob}
{Browning1983}


\end{otherlanguage}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The command `\AdaptNoteOpt` is not more defined by `fnpct`. It is substituted by `\AdaptNote` which have a completely different syntax. See the documentation of `fnpc` and here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511158/231952. Moreover try to create a MWE (**minimal** working example) that can be simply copied and compiled. (Your code loads a font not available on the normal distributions.)

Comment: @Ivan, I simplified the code and removed all unknown fonts. But, I do not have much experience with fnpct, so all I have to do Is to replace \AdaptNoteOpt with \AdaptNote??

Comment: Note that your question refers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123814/consecutive-footcite-commands-and-separating-commas-in-the-text but your MWE does not use any `\footcite` command. Anyway in the answer below I assumed the problem was the same as the one of that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the MWE here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123888/231952, simply replace
`\AdaptNoteOpt\footcite\multfootcite`
with the code you find in the `fnpct` documentation, § 7.15:

```
\AdaptNote\footcite{oo+m}[footnote]{%
  \setfnpct{dont-mess-around}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {#NOTE{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#NOTE[#1]{#3}}{#NOTE[#1][#2]{#3}}}%
}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{fnpct}

%\setfnpct{ranges=true} 
\AdaptNote\footcite{oo+m}[footnote]{%
\setfnpct{dont-mess-around}%
\IfNoValueTF{#1}
{#NOTE{#3}}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#NOTE[#1]{#3}}{#NOTE[#1][#2]{#3}}}%
}

\begin{document}
Text\footcite{knuth:ct:a}

Text\footcite{knuth:ct:b}\footcite{ctan}


Text\footcite{knuth:ct:c}\footcite{companion}\footcite{knuth:ct:d}

Text\footcite{knuth:ct:a}\footcite{knuth:ct:b}\footcite{knuth:ct:c}\footcite{knuth:ct:d}\footcite{companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also simplify the syntax defining a new `\multfootcite` command through

```
\MultVariant{\footcite}
\setfnpct{mult-fn-delim =/}
```

Obviously you can change the `mult-fn-delim`. To use the default delimiter (`;`) simply comment the second line

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{fnpct}

\AdaptNote\footcite{oo+m}[footnote]{%
\setfnpct{dont-mess-around}%
\IfNoValueTF{#1}
{#NOTE{#3}}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#NOTE[#1]{#3}}{#NOTE[#1][#2]{#3}}}%
}

\MultVariant{\footcite}
\setfnpct{mult-fn-delim =/} 

\begin{document}
Text\footcite{knuth:ct:a}

Text\multfootcite{knuth:ct:b/ctan}


Text\multfootcite{knuth:ct:c/companion/knuth:ct:d}

Text\multfootcite{knuth:ct:a/knuth:ct:b/knuth:ct:c/knuth:ct:d/companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```