# Can Microtype Change the Kerning Between a Dot or Comma and a Footnotemark?

Tags: footnotes, microtype, kerning

Relatet to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56094/37428): Is it possible to change the kerning between a punctuation mark and a footnotemark with microtype (or any other kerning-method)?

(I know of package `fnpct`, but I would rather like my footnotemarks *behind* punctuation marks)

Comment: You know that `fnpct` only requires that `\footnote` is _input_ before the punctuation mark? The _output_ is of course customizable and in the default setting the footnote marks _are_ output behind the punctuation marks!

Comment: If by "behind" you mean to the right of then `fnpct` does put the footnote marks behind the punctuation marks by default. It just moves it a little closer than LaTeX normally does.

Comment: @clemens Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm not sure: either my comment doesn't answer the question because the question is about methods other than using `fnpct` or my comment does answer it and then this question very much looks like a duplicate of the linked question (IMHO).

Comment: @clemens I found this doing janitorial work. To be honest, i don't care if this gets an answer, or is closed as dupe. Would prefer it over closing it as unclear.

Comment: @Johannes_B I added something

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm mistaken I believe the question is a misunderstanding about `fnpct`: the package only requires that `\footnote` is *input* before the respective punctuation. The *output* is customizable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\begin{document}

text\footnote{text}.

\setfnpct{punct-after}
text\footnote{text}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Nevertheless, I prefer to put the `\footnote` commands also in the source behind the punctuation, so I can easily comment them in or out.

Comment: @Daniel It is way easier with TeX to look ahead than behind (which is why `fnpct` does that). But probably a solution using sfcodes may be a way...

Comment: Despite the OP's misconception about `fnpct`, do you know the answer to their title question? I have a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435760/how-do-i-use-the-fnpct-package-with-natbib).