# How do I use the `fnpct` package with natbib?

Tags: citing, footnotes, natbib, fnpct

I'm using `natbib` with the `super` option, which generates citation call-outs in the form of superscript numerals. These numerals look quite a bit like footnote markers. I'd like to use the [fnpct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56094/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-change-kerning-between-commas-full-stops-and-foo) package to move the citation call-out numerals outside of the punctuation and improve the kerning. Unfortunately, by default it only works with `\footnote`s instead of natbib's `\cite`s. According to chapter 8 of the documentation and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78837/95221), you can hack `fnpct` together with Biblatex by adding the command `\AdaptNoteOpt\cite\multcite` to the preamble. But I'm using `natbib` and BibTeX instead of `biblatex`, and if I try adding that command my TeX capacity gets exceeded.

MWE: trying to compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super,compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\AdaptNoteOpt\cite\multcite

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{Anderson}.

\end{document}
```

results in the error message

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
>   \l__xparse_args_tl ...{Anderson}{Anderson}{Anderso
>   n}{Anderson}{Anderson}{And...

It seems that for some reason the `\AdaptNoteOpt` command is causing the parser to duplicate `{Anderson}` umpteen times. How do I fix this?

**Edit**: The reason that I want to do this is explain in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435907/how-can-i-improve-the-kerning-of-citation-footnotes-made-with-natbib). I want the citation superscripts to be outside of the punctuation. If I do it manually (`Hello world.\cite{Anderson}`), then there's a bit too much horizontal space between the period and the superscript. I'd like to bring the superscript in a point or two closer to the punctuation mark (although not directly above it), which apparently can be done using the `fnpct` package. If there's an easier way to do that which doesn't require the package, I'd accept that as well.

Comment: You don't need this with Biblatex, do you? You can switch the automatic punctuation stuff on and use that. If Biblatex is an option, you can use it with the `natbib` compatibility setting.

Comment: I wouldn't sacrifice logical punctuation for improved kerning. In any case, where should the markers be for your language or for the requirements you need to meet? That's really what matters - it isn't a case of what you happen to fancy doing, but what's correct for your linguistic and submission/publication context.

Comment: @cfr Edited to clarify.

Comment: Depending on engine, `microtype` might be an option?

Comment: @cfr I'm using Microtype in my real use case, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Well obviously just loading it wouldn't help. You'd have to tweak its settings to get the results you want.

Comment: @cfr I was told that a big part of the appeal of the `microtype` package was that you could indeed just load it and it fixes lots of problems like that by default. Do you know how to adjust footnote kerning in Microtype without needing to read the 250-page manual?

Comment: You don't need `natbib` to get the error, by the way.

Comment: I just mentioned `microtype` as a possibility since it has sophisticated ways to adjust kerning. Yes, you can in many cases load it and it fixes problems. But what you want isn't to fix a problem. You want something non-standard. So, obviously it won't 'fix' that by default: you'd have to configure it. I don't know if it could do what you want or not. It was just a suggestion to look at. By all means, feel free to ignore the suggestion completely.

Answer (score 4):

#### With `fnpct` v1.x (updated answer Jan 2021)

With version 1.x it works natively:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super,compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\AdaptNote\cite{oom}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {#NOTE{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#NOTE[#1]{#3}}{#NOTE[#1][#2]{#3}}}%
}

\begin{document}

Hello world\cite{Anderson}.

\end{document}
```

#### With `fnpct` v0.x (original answer)

`natbib` defines `\cite` with `\DeclareRobustCommand\cite` which causes a problem here.

The definition of `\cite` is now `\protect\cite␣` where the name of the internal macro `\cite␣` *includes a trailing space* which I've indicated with `␣`.

A solution is

```
\expandafter\AdaptNoteOpt\csname cite \endcsname\multcite
```

where the blank after `cite` is crucial.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super,compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\expandafter\AdaptNoteOpt\csname cite \endcsname\multcite

\begin{document}

Hello world\cite{Anderson}.

\end{document}
```

[image]